# Displaying data that does not match criteria for Index/Match function

Tags: excel, indexing, match

I am trying to make a simple search with different tables. I am trying to display multiple contacts attached to a customer ID but when using Index/Match formula will continue to display data that does not match the criteria (Customer ID).

[image: Output]

[image: Formulas]

Comment: You will have to research: how to display multiple matches in a list. There are nice tutorials around being either text/video. Just Google and you will find! It features the Aggregate function.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Got everything worked out after a couple videos and an article.